# ngx-mat-intl-tel-input not working in angular 14

Tags: angular, angular14, libphonenumber, ngx-international-phone-number

I have installed angular material and cdk for angular 14 version
`i want to user  import { NgxMatIntlTelInputModule } from "ngx-mat-intl-tel-input";`
when i import this library its geeting error. the error message
'"ngx-mat-intl-tel-input"' has no exported member named 'NgxMatIntlTelInputModule'. Did you mean 'NgxMatIntlTelInputComponent'?

How to use ngx-mat-intl-tel-input for use phone number validation with the country code in angular 14
the demo url : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-mat-intl-tel-inpu-demo

how to phone number blank or clear when we change country code in this
ngx-mat-intl-tel-input
as per below code

```
                            <ngx-mat-intl-tel-input 
                            [preferredCountries]="['in', 'us']"
                            [enablePlaceholder]="true"
                            [enableSearch]="true" 
                            formControlName="phone"
                            name="phone" #phone
                         >
                          </ngx-mat-intl-tel-input>                       
                        </mat-form-field>  
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      name: 'User',
      phone: new FormControl('+93  234234243',[Validators.required])
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are installing ngx-mat-intl-tel-input with version [5.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-intl-tel-input?activeTab=readme) which is the latest version that supports Angular 14.

It has been migrated to the [standalone component](https://github.com/tanansatpal/ngx-mat-intl-tel-input/blob/d3e50c98309a3d168ea70e1b2cc766457e56ca06/projects/ngx-mat-intl-tel-input/src/lib/ngx-mat-intl-tel-input.component.ts#L104). And the `NgxMatIntlTelInputModule` is no longer available.

Thus, you need to import the `NgxMatIntlTelInputComponent` in your component assuming that your component is a standalone component.

```
import { NgxMatIntlTelInputComponent } from 'ngx-mat-intl-tel-input';

@Component({
  ...,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NgxMatIntlTelInputComponent]
})
export class YourComponent { }
```

If your components are not standalone, you need to import the `NgxMatIntlTelInputComponent` in the `declarations` array in the root module of your Angular application.

```
import { NgxMatIntlTelInputComponent } from 'ngx-mat-intl-tel-input';

@NgModule({
  ...,
  declarations: [NgxMatIntlTelInputComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit aside, but for posterity, those looking for a raw implementation of [IntlPhone](https://www.github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) it's a matter of

- add the CSS via the docs
- update your angular.json scripts to ref the lib's util.js
- @ViewChild to ref the desired input element
- afterViewInit
- grab the formatted number out of the IntlPhone instance.

e.g.

### Ang.json

```
{ ...
  compilerOptions: {
    scripts: ["node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js"]
  }
...}
```

### Component

```
export class FooComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('phone', { static: true })
    phoneEl!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  intlPhone: any;
  ...
  ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.intlPhone = intlTelInput(this.phoneEl.nativeElement, {
            utilsScript: 'node_modules/intl-tel-input/build/js/utils.js'
        });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const data = ...;
    data.phone = this.intlPhone.getNumber();
    return data;
  }
```